# java me textfield

Tags: java-me, mobile

i want to have default text in a textfield which disappears when the textfield gets focus. similar to the google search box in firefox.

also with java me is it possible to set a background image for a display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of your second question is easy. Unless you use canvas, it is not possible.

AFAIK you cannot handle focus events on a textfield in J2ME so it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry this is not possible either. Can you consider using a third party library for user interface? LWUIT is easy to learn: https://lwuit.dev.java.net/nonav/tutorial/index.html